# CImage::Save file name formatting

Tags: c++, formatting, filenames, cimage

In CImage::Save() function, how can I change the file name?

I saw MSDN(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06f3fhw(v=vs.120).aspx), but I cannot understand.

Also, every example I found used a constant file name. Like below

```
CImage.A;
A.Save("test.bmp");
```

I want to save multiple bmp files. (test1, test2, test3.... test'n'...) In other words, how can I do formatting in the first argument of the function???

Comment: Unclear: `A.Save("test.bmp")` saves a `CImage` into a named file.  As you only have one `CImage` in your question, why do you want to save it to multiple files?

Comment: Because, I'll use CImage::Save function in while (1). The CImage will gonna change every time. I don't want the function to overwrite again and again.  @RichardCritten

Comment: Then just use a counter, append it to the root filename and then add-on the extension. `std::stringstream` can be used for this.